# JavaScript for reflowing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Looking for a plugin to flow text like google currents or other iPhone apps where you would swipe left or right to get the next page.

Does this exist? Or is reflowing text with JavaScript too memory intensive?

Comment: I think you need to explaing "flow text" a little better, not everyone is familiar with your favorite apps. Maybe you're just looking for the always great [**`<marquee>`**](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ8Bm/10/) tag ?

Comment: No I am sorry, I guess flowing text is meant that I want to take text and flow it into divs according to the divs height and width (no overflow). Then hopefully allow a animation between divs when an event is triggered. I guess another popular application that does this is Flippad or the kindle app on the iPhone. Essentially instead of scrolling vertically you would scroll (flip) horizontally

Answer (score 1):

I found this link  after read your question .i assumed flow test is like sliding page by page atleast div by div. regarding that ...i found below one .Hope that will helpfull.

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/

Comment: Thanks this is a helpful animation but not quite what I am looking for. I am looking for the page transition animation you see so frequently on Iphone apps when you swipe left or right.